# Illegal escape in a leet Java program

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm creating a very basic converter program from the alphabet to a [Leet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) character. I have the project finished, but will not compile correctly because I have a few "illegal escape characters"... 
My teacher needs what he gave us, for example the letter m would be //\
But that doesn't work out too well... is there a way that this will be able to work?

```
case 'm': case 'M': 
System.out.printf ("%s /\/\ \n", ch);  // m is supposed to look like /\/\
break;
case 'n': case 'N':
System.out.printf ("%s |\| \n", ch);   // n is supposed to look like |\|
break;
```

The letter "v" needs some help as well...   to look like  /

I need to have the \n after for the spacing, or is there another way?! Even when I took it out it still had the same error.

Just very new to this...
Thank you!

Comment: if you want to print a backslash you need to escape it as `\\\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to print backslash character, you need to escape it with another one like this:

`System.out.printf ("%s /\\/\\ \n", ch);  // m is supposed to look like /\/\`

Comment: OHH! Okay thank you! I completely forgot about that hah.. whoops.